# sending requests to elasticsearch through kibana without authentication

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am writing a plugin to kibana.

I want to be able to communicate with elasticsearch and I have shield installed.

For now, the only way I managed to do so, is by sending a request through the server such as:

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    path: '/someFunction',
    handler: async function (request, reply) {
      const exec = require('child_process').exec;
      exec("curl --user admin:111111 -XPOST 'localhost:9200/filebeat-*/_search?pretty' -d ' { --someQuery-- }'", function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
          throw err;
        } else {
          console.log(JSON.parse(res));
          reply(JSON.parse(res));
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

I am sure there is a better way to do that, as I can see the `esResp` and the `searchSource` in other places in the code.

The authentication is already inserted in the login so there is no need for me to expose the password hard-coded in the server.

How do i do that? how to use the kibana built-in communication to elasticserach?

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it..

```
return es.search({
          index: 'filebeat-*',
          body: {
            "size": 0,
            "aggs": {
              "group_by_product": {
                "terms": {
                  "field": "product"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }).then(function (resp) {
          resp.aggregations.group_by_product.buckets.forEach(function (obj) {
          });
        });
```

Just needed to use the elasticsearch nodeJs module (es).